# Error in compiling c++ program in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I can't get my following c++ program compiled in Visual Studio 2010. I already have a working build of the same code so I know the code is correct. But I have no idea with what or how it was compiled.

So I would appreciate if someone could just copy the code and try to compile it in VS 2010.

Code:

http://codepad.org/4VtrVBdK

*new*:

Ok, I did editing according to the comments below. Now the only problems that seem to have remained are related to calls to the overloaded functions. So how to go about it?

Comment: If you have compile errors, you should cut+paste them into your question.

Comment: fyi, there are better ways of pasting example code around. e.g. this site not only highlights code but also compiles it and runs it for you.. http://codepad.org/cXvCUcPV

Comment: I am getting very generic errors, I think someone will have to actually compile the code to see and make sense of the errors.

Comment: @Assaf ;) thx for tht..i am new over here...

Comment: @user597272: Baloney.  I didn't have to look at the code where the error occurred.  Remember that there are some VERY experienced users on SO and we've seen most errors hundreds of times before.

Comment: @user597272: See the "Answers" section underneath?  SO separates answers from comments (and then there can be comments on the answers as well).

Comment: blimey...actually i missed copying using namespace std; but thts an error on my side.....still cant get it to compile even with using the namespace...

Comment: @user597272: Oh, so the file you gave us isn't even the code you're trying to compile?  How do you expect any useful feedback then?  Paste the errors, since I'm obviously getting different errors than you are, since I'm compiling a different file.

Comment: I meant i was tryin to fix the file while i was uploadin it and had already added "usin namespace std" ....thts the only diff between the code...

Comment: has this anything to do with genetic algorithms?

Comment: @JohnIdol yes actually its a program i have been doing for my project in cs...its comparison of common page replacement algorithms compared to using genetic algorithms...its very basic though...

Comment: @user597272 yes, but the problem is that it doesn't compile, which has nothing to do with the fact that this is a GA, might as well be the space shuttle firmware :)

Answer (score 2):

> so I know the code is correct

What you "know" is false.  The code is wrong in *many* ways.  Here is but one example:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<GPNO;i++)    //SORTING ACCORDING TO FITNESS
    for(unsigned int j=i+1;j<GPNO;j++)
        if((gp[i]->fitness)>(gp[j]->fitness))
        {
            gp[i]->mycopy(tmp);
            gp[j]->mycopy(gp[i]);
            tmp->mycopy(gp[j]);
        }



for(i=1;i<=no;i++)
{
    gp[i]->mycopy(gp[GPNO-i]);
}
```

In the second `for` loop, `i` is undeclared.  I suspect the original compiler was VC6, which allowed this.

Another problem is the way you're calling `pow`.  You call it with macros (which are patently evil for this purpose), for instance:

```
pf[i].frq+=(unsigned int)pow(2,2*PF-1);
```

And the compiler doesn't know which version of `pow` you had in mind.  Case in point for macros being evil for this purpose.  Do this:

```
pf[i].frq+=(unsigned int)pow(2.0,2*PF-1);
```

Or better yet, get rid of the macros.

Another example of your code being *wrong*:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "math.h"
```

None of these includes are part of the Standard.  If you can get them to compile, its only because your compiler was anticipating your mistake.  But it's still a mistake.

Comment: I'd favor `2.0` instead of `(double)2`.  The fewer casts, the better, as a rule.  But bit shifts would be better yet.

Comment: hmmm..yeah..got on phone with the colleague who sent me the program...turns out it was actually compiled in vc6... now the thing is how can i get it to compile in vs 2010... i m usin win 7 and so cant get vc6 to work properly in it...

Comment: @user:  fix it.  you should be able to get the syntax errors fixes fairly easily.

Comment: Shall I post the working executable of the code?? I wanted to but as I am new here i cant seem to post more than one hyperlink...so if i had to how to go abt it???

Comment: @user:  Don't post an executable.  You shouldn't have even posted a hyperlink in the first place, and I probably shouldn't have downloaded it.  What you should do is post your code **directly** in your post.

Comment: Also, `(unsigned int)x` is ill-formed.

Comment: hmmm...srry for tht... the codepad thing hit me later...actually der was some parsing error when i tried to post the code directly...

Comment: okay...i have taken care of most of the improperly declared vars...the errors have reduced..still cant compile it though..any idea how should i go abt fixing the overloaded functions..specific point outs will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `using namespace std;`

Comment: blimey...actually i missed copying using namespace std; but thts an error on my side.....still cant get it to compile even with using the namespace...